# Probability of having lots of unique elements

Tags: probability

If you sample $n$ integers from the range $1$ to $n$ inclusive it seems intuitive that you are likely to get a lot of numbers exactly once.  Call $X_n$ the number of integers you get that occur exactly once in your sample.  Is there a nice simple way of showing the following for all $n\geq 2$.

$$\exists a,b >0\text{ such that } P(X_n \leq an) \leq 2^{-bn} $$

Comment: You can use martingale bounds for this. See Azuma-Hoeffding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good model for large $n$ is a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda=1$.  You would expect about $\frac ne \approx 0.3688n$ numbers not to be selected at all and the same number to be selected once. I don't have an easy way to calculate the distribution of the number that are selected exactly once.